# I am not able to deploy services in Apache ignite while working with .net

Tags: .net, ignite

If I set the client mode to true by below line

```
Ignition.ClientMode = true;
```

I am not able to deploy the service. The code I used for deployment is

```
   ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();
            serviceConfiguration.Name = "FService";
            serviceConfiguration.MaxPerNodeCount = 4;
            serviceConfiguration.TotalCount = 10;
            serviceConfiguration.Service = new MyService();
            ignite.GetCluster().GetServices().Deploy(serviceConfiguration);
```

The code used for fetching the service is

```
  IMyService proxy = ignite.GetServices().GetServiceProxy<IMyService>("FService", false);
```

> I am getting exception like service not found

The same code is working perfectly if I set the client mode to false

```
Ignition.ClientMode = false;
```

Please suggest to me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have code for this service on other nodes?

If your node is Server, and code is only available on current node, it will be deployed locally.

But if node is Client, and code is not available on any server nodes, service won't be deployed.

Comment: I am running the ignite server on a different windows machine by running the ignite.bat file from the setup. Can you suggest me how i can deploy this service on different machine(Server) and can connect from my local machine(Client).

Comment: You should put assemblies there which contain code from this service. Please see `-Assembly` parameter in the [running documentation](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/standalone-nodes).

Comment: I have filed a ticket [IGNITE-12284](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12284);